# How to transmit PostgreSQL DB Password in Plain Text / Cleartext from NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres, pg-promise

#### Expected behavior

Password should be transmitted in plain text (cleartext), without md5 hashing. Because MD5 is not FIPS compliant.

#### Actual behavior

Password always uses md5 hashing.

#### Steps to reproduce

**pg_hba.conf** file has "md5" option. It cannot be changed to "password" in my case.
Role in **pg_authid** has password with "md5" prefix.

According to PostgreSQL documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-password.html):

> If a password was encrypted using the md5 setting, then it can be used only for the md5 and password authentication method specifications (again, with the password transmitted in plain text in the latter case).

How password can be transmitted in plain text (cleartext), without md5 hashing?

#### Used libraries

- pg-promise: 10.11.0
- pg-protocol: 1.5.0
- pg (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg): 8.7.1

PostgreSQL version: 9.3

Node.js: 12.20.1

OS: Linux/Mac

Comment: Only if you change `md5` to `password` in `pg_hba.conf`. But don't do that. Your question is unclear: there is no PostgreSQL version 8.7.1.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I think the OP is talking about the version of the Postgresql Node connector module, but you're right that it would be nice to know the version of the database itself.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe PostgreSQL version is 9.3

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I need to avoid crypo function call with md5 algorithm on NodeJS server side. Because I get error:
```internal/crypto/hash.js:48
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
Error: error:060800C8:digital envelope routines:EVP_DigestInit_ex:disabled for FIPS
    at new Hash (internal/crypto/hash.js:48:19)
    at Object.createHash (crypto.js:115:10)
    at md5 (/.../node_modules/pg/lib/utils.js:174:17)
{
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  function: 'EVP_DigestInit_ex',
  reason: 'disabled for FIPS',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_DISABLED_FOR_FIPS'
}```

Comment: So MD5 is not FIPS compliant.

Comment: I am pretty sure "plain text" isn't FIPS compliant either. You don't less security you want **more**. Upgrade to a recent Postgres version (12,13,14) - which you should do anyway if you care about security - then use scram authentication which is most likely FIPS compliant

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author asks all the wrong questions.